# ListView is sending entire model

Tags: data-binding, model, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following code snippet:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<ContactViewModel>()
    .Name("PortalInfo_NonAddedJobContacts")
    .TagName("div")
    .BindTo(Model.NonAddedContacts)
    .ClientTemplateId("nonAddedJobContactsTemplate")
    .DataSource(ds => ds
        .Model(model => 
        {
            model.Id(x => x.Id);
            model.Field(x => x.ContactType);
            model.Field(x => x.DisplayName);
        })
    )
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "border: none;" })
)
```

I would think that by telling the control that I only want the Id, ContactType and DisplayName that Kendo would be smart enough to only send across those 3 field when generating the control.  However, when I look at fiddler, it's using the entire ContactViewModel, which is extremely bloated with a lot of information that I don't need.

How can I get Kendo to ONLY create the 3 fields that I need?

Wall of text Html that Kendo created:

```
jQuery(function(){jQuery("#PortalInfo_NonAddedJobContacts").kendoListView({"dataSource":{"type":"aspnetmvc-ajax","transport":{"read":{"url":""},"prefix":""},"serverPaging":true,"serverSorting":true,"serverFiltering":true,"serverGrouping":true,"serverAggregates":true,"filter":[],"schema":{"data":"Data","total":"Total","errors":"Errors","model":{"id":"Id","fields":{"ContactType":{"type":"string"},"ActivityStatus":{"type":"string"},"StatusDisplay":{"type":"string"},"Addresses":{"type":"object"},"Phones":{"type":"object"},"Emails":{"type":"object"},"Deleted":{"type":"boolean"},"InsuranceCompanyContactId":{"type":"number","defaultValue":null},"ParentContactTypeId":{"type":"number","defaultValue":null},"MappedContactId":{"type":"number","defaultValue":null},"MarketingRep":{"type":"string"},"InsuranceCompanyName":{"type":"string"},"PrimaryPhone":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"PrimaryPhoneNumbersOnly":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"HomePhone":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"HomePhoneNumbersOnly":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"OfficePhone":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"OfficePhoneNumbersOnly":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"CellPhone":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"CellPhoneNumbersOnly":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"OtherPhone":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"Fax":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"FaxNumbersOnly":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"PrimaryEmail":{"type":"string"},"PrimaryStreet1":{"type":"string"},"PrimaryStreet2":{"type":"string"},"PrimaryCity":{"type":"string"},"PrimaryState":{"type":"string"},"PrimaryPostal":{"type":"string"},"PrimaryAddressFormatted":{"type":"string"},"GoogleMapHtml":{"type":"string"},"Tags":{"type":"object"},"LastActivityDate":{"type":"date","defaultValue":null},"IsEditable":{"type":"boolean"},"Id":{"type":"number"},"CompanyId":{"type":"number","defaultValue":null},"CompanyPerson":{"type":"string"},"ContactTypeId":{"type":"number"},"ContactTypeName":{"type":"string"},"TypePath":{"type":"string"},"FirstName":{"type":"string"},"LastName":{"type":"string"},"CompanyName":{"type":"string"},"DisplayName":{"type":"string"},"AddressID":{"type":"number","defaultValue":null},"Street1":{"type":"string"},"Street2":{"type":"string"},"City":{"type":"string"},"State":{"type":"string"},"PostalCode":{"type":"string"},"Chalkboard":{"type":"string"},"Title":{"type":"string"},"InsuranceCompanyId":{"type":"number","defaultValue":null},"MarketingRepId":{"type":"number","defaultValue":null},"Website":{"type":"string"},"Inactive":{"type":"boolean"},"FullName":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"Buckets":{"type":"object"},"Activities":{"type":"object"},"Rois":{"type":"object"},"FormattedDateUpdated":{"type":"string"},"TotalLeads":{"type":"number"},"TotalReturn":{"type":"number"},"TotalInvested":{"type":"number"},"ROI":{"editable":false,"type":"number"},"ROIPercentage":{"editable":false,"type":"number"}}}},"data":{"Data":[{"ContactType":"Property Management Company","ActivityStatus":null,"StatusDisplay":null,"Addresses":[{"Id":1975,"AddressTypeId":2,"AddressType":"Business","Street1":"2122 W. Lone Cactus Dr., Suite 5 ","Street2":null,"City":"Phoenix","State":"AZ","PostalCode":"85027","FormattedAddress":"2122 W. Lone Cactus Dr., Suite 5  Phoenix, AZ 85027"}],"Phones":[{"Id":1329,"PhoneTypeId":4,"PhoneType":"Work","PhoneTypeDisplay":"W:","Number":"602-862-9307","NumberOnly":"6028629307"}],"Emails":[],"Deleted":false,"InsuranceCompanyContactId":null,"ParentContactTypeId":null,"MappedContactId":null,"MarketingRep":"","InsuranceCompanyName":"","PrimaryPhone":"602-862-9307","PrimaryPhoneNumbersOnly":"6028629307","HomePhone":"","HomePhoneNumbersOnly":"","OfficePhone":"602-862-9307","OfficePhoneNumbersOnly":"6028629307","CellPhone":"","CellPhoneNumbersOnly":"","OtherPhone":"","Fax":"","FaxNumbersOnly":"","PrimaryEmail":"","PrimaryStreet1":"2122 W. Lone Cactus Dr., Suite 5 ","PrimaryStreet2":null,"PrimaryCity":"Phoenix","PrimaryState":"AZ","PrimaryPostal":"85027","PrimaryAddressFormatted":"2122 W. Lone Cactus Dr., Suite 5  Phoenix, AZ 85027","GoogleMapHtml":"2122+W.+Lone+Cactus+Dr,+Suite+5+,+Phoenix,+AZ,+85027","Tags":null,"LastActivityDate":null,"IsEditable":true,"Id":2052,"CompanyId":null,"CompanyPerson":"Company","ContactTypeId":32,"ContactTypeName":null,"TypePath":null,"FirstName":null,"LastName":null,"CompanyName":"AMPM Water Damage Restoration","DisplayName":"AMPM Water Damage
```

Comment: Could you shed some light on why this is an issue?

Comment: Because if I have 100 customers, and each customer has 100k of data, that's 10mb of data that would be sent across the internet.  On a slow, mobile connection, this could take an excessive amount of time.  I'd prefer to send 3 fields for 100 customers instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kendo is going to create the ListView control based on whatever the Model is you are passing to it.

If you want the dataset to be more compact, you're going to need to provide and bind to a more specialized ViewModel.

Create a class along the lines of:

```
public class ContactListViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ContactType { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

Then have your controller method return a collection of `ContactListViewModel` and bind your ListView to that.